# Is every 1-million-connected graph rigid in 3D?

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

It is an old result that every $6$-connected graph is rigid in $\mathbb{R}^2$:

> Lovász, László, and Yechiam Yemini. "On generic rigidity in the plane." *SIAM Journal on Algebraic Discrete Methods* **3**, no. 1 (1982): 91-98.
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1137/0603009).

It is natural to hope that sufficiently high connectivity implies rigidity in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

> ***Q.*** Is it known that there is some $k$ such that any $k$-connected graph is
> generically rigid in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Informally, $G$ is rigid if the distances between vertices connected in $G$
determine all the distances between vertices not connected in $G$.
More formally, $G$ is *generically rigid* in $\mathbb{R}^d$ if every generic representation in $\mathbb{R}^d$
is [infinitesimally rigid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rigidity)—no
infinitesimal length-preserving velocities (if they exist) can be extended.
An embedded graph representation (a *framework*) is *generic* if the coordinates of its configuration do not satisfy
any non-trivial algebraic equation with rational coefficients.

There have been recent advances in 3D rigidity and I am unclear on the current status
of this question ***Q***.

Comment: For the reader: $k$-connected means that there are $>k$ vertices, and removing any $< k$ vertices yields a connected graph.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: I believe the implication direction is: If infinitesimally rigid in $\mathbb{R}^3$, then $m \ge 3 n - 6$, where $m$ is the number of edges and $n$ the number of vertices. It is iff in the plane (with $m \ge 2 n - 3$). The flexible, generic double-banana satisfies $m = 3n-6$.

Comment: I do not think that even on the plane it is iff: glue two large complete graphs by a vertex. Actually, if for certain $k$ vertices there are more than $3k-6$ edges between them, and total number of edges is $3n-6$, it can not be rigid (analogously in dimension 2).

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Sorry, my misinterpretation of JieGao lecture notes: It is, instead of $m$, the rank of the rigidity matrix $R$---"disregarding global translation and rotation, the framework $G(P)$ is infinitesimally rigid if and only if rank$(R) = 2n − 3$." [PDF](https://www3.cs.stonybrook.edu/~jgao/CSE590-fall05/notes/lecture3.pdf).

Comment: Adding nothing but a physical example to what has already been described. A door is a physical realization of an infinitely connected graph that is not rigid.

Comment: @YCor Do you mean that removing any $<k$ vertices yields a connected graph? Otherwise cycles would not be 2-connected.

Comment: @M.Winter you're right, I misquoted [this Wikipedia definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-vertex-connected_graph), sorry for making a mess :(

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update.** The recent paper [Every $d(d+1)$-connected graph is globally rigid in $\mathbb{R}^d$](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.02028) by Soma Villányi gives a positive answer to the question.

**Old Answer.** I think this is still an open problem, but recent work of [Clinch, Jackson, and Tanigawa](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00207) (almost) shows every $12$-connected graph is generically rigid in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

In that paper, they prove that $12$-connectivity is sufficient to force rigidity in the $C_2^1$-cofactor matroid (see the paper for precise definitions). In an [earlier paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00205), the same authors showed that the $C_2^1$-cofactor matroid is the unique maximal abstract $3$-rigidity matroid.  A long-standing conjecture in rigidity theory is that the unique maximal abstract $3$-rigidity matroid is in fact the generic $3$-dimensional rigidity matroid. If you believe this conjecture, then the answer to your quesiton is yes, with one million replaced with $12$.

**Acknowledgement.** The old answer is entirely due to Katie Clinch.

Answer (score 5):

update: this is an answer without generic configuration assumption

I am afraid that no. Take two half-planes with a common boundary line $a$, and many points both on $a$ and in these half-planes. Join by edges all pairs of points in the same half-plane. Now rotate one of the half-planes around $a$.

Comment: I can't claim to fully understand the terms used in the question, but I don't think this is a counterexample to *generic* rigidity.

Comment: My apologies for not defining "generic." Now added.